# Javascript/jQuery scrollTop jumping up and down when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that will jump between each instance of a class ("highlighted") every time to call `gonext().`

Here is the full code:

```js
var currentPos = 0;
function gonext() {
  var pos = $(".highlighted").eq(currentPos).position();
  console.log(Math.round(pos.top));
  $(".highlighted").eq(currentPos).css("color", "red");
  currentPos++;
  $(".main").scrollTop(pos.top);
}
```

```css
.main {
  height: 100px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<hr>
<button onclick="gonext()">Got to Next</button>
<hr>

<div class="main">
    <div><span class="highlighted">a</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">s</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">v</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">a</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">s</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">v</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">a</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">s</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">v</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">a</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">s</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">v</span></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that as soon as it scrolls to the next position it scrolls up and then down.

See the console log positions for more info.

How can I fix this so that it just scrolls to the next one etc...without the up / down jump?

Comment: FYI, you can put the code in a runnable code container, so it's easier for other people to debug your code.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: did that for ya

Comment: I appreciate it...thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add some calculation of `.main` top and scrollTop. Don't forget to add condition to check last `.highlighted` element in `.main` container. Otherwise it'll throw an error.

```js
var currentPos = 0;
function gonext() {
  if($(".highlighted").eq(currentPos).length > 0){
    
    var mainTop = $(".main").position().top;
    var mainScrlTop = $(".main").scrollTop();
    
    var pos = $(".highlighted").eq(currentPos).position();
    $(".highlighted").eq(currentPos).css("color", "red");
    $(".main").scrollTop(pos.top - mainTop + mainScrlTop);
    
    currentPos++;
  }
}
```

```css
    .main {
      height: 100px;
      border:1px solid grey;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr>
<button onclick="gonext()">Got to Next</button>
<hr>

<div class="main">
    <div><span class="highlighted">a</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">s</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">v</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">a</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">s</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">v</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">a</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">s</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">v</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">a</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">s</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">v</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, basically the `position()` is not something you looking for.

From my personal experience, whenever I want to scroll to some elements, `offsetTop` is more accurate.

```js
var currentPos = 0;
function gonext() {
  var pos = $(".highlighted").eq(currentPos)[0].offsetTop;
  
  $(".highlighted").eq(currentPos).css("color", "red");
  $(".main").scrollTop(pos);
  console.log(currentPos)
  console.log($(".highlighted").eq(currentPos)[0].offsetTop)
  currentPos++;
}
```

```css
.main {
  height: 100px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<hr>
<button onclick="gonext()">Got to Next</button>
<hr>

<div class="main">
    <div><span class="highlighted">a</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">s</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">v</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">a</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">s</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">v</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">a</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">s</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">v</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">a</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">s</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">v</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working well except that I can't see the current highlighted class..it's hidden. You can see that when you click the button, the currentPos  changes color but I need to see it

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the scrolled height in addition to the position or offset.

```
$(".main").scrollTop(pos.top + $(".main").get(0).scrollTop);
```

When you use overflow scrolling containers, the offset or position function tends to calculate from the relative position, not the scrolled position.

See a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tive/e3Ls529c/

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to walk the indexes of the list items.
Like https://jsfiddle.net/vL2sayt4/15/

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<hr>
<button class="gonext">Got to Next</button>
<hr>
<div class="main">
    <div><span class="highlighted">a</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">s</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">v</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">a</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">s</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">v</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">a</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">s</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">v</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">a</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">s</span></div>
    <div><span class="highlighted">v</span></div>
</div>
<pre class="console"></pre>
```

```css
.main {
  height: 100px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  overflow: scroll;
  display:block;
}
.console {
  display:block;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```js
(function($){
    var itemsLength  = $('div.main div span.highlighted').length;
    var curIndex     = 0;
    var cwindow      = $('.console');
    var button       = $('button.gonext');
    var consolelog = function(message){
        var text  = cwindow.innerHTML;
      message += "\n";
      cwindow.prepend(message);
    };
    var gonext = function(){
       consolelog('Button:click:curIndex:'+curIndex);
       consolelog('Button:click:itemLength:'+itemsLength);
       var listItem = $( "div.main div span.highlighted" ).eq( curIndex );
       // all black
       $("div.main div span.highlighted").css("color", "black");
       // current red 
       listItem.css("color", "red");
        curIndex ++;
        if(curIndex > itemsLength) curIndex = 0;
    };
    button.click(function(){
        gonext();
    });
})(jQuery)
```